# PHP Copy function Not Working in Joomla

Tags: php, function, joomla

I need to copy image one path to another path.

Here is My code :

```
$sourspath = JUri::root().'media/truematrimony/profiles/pending/'.$totbookmar.'';

$descpath = JUri::root().'media/truematrimony/profiles/kmprofile/'.$totbookmar.''; 

$status = copy($sourspath, $descpath) or die("Could not copy file contents");
```

---

Comment: Good luck. If you have any problem (`var_dump($sourspath, $descpath)` displays wrong paths or `copy()` returns `false` or displays a warning) don't doubt coming back.

Comment: string(88) "http://temsqpp.com/media/matsts/profiles/pending/watermark-K34691_pho_1.png" 
string(90) "http://temsqpp.com/media/matsts/profiles/profils/watermark-K34691_pho_1.png" Could not copy file contents

Comment: Please take into account that we cannot read you mind, peek your monitor over your shoulders or read large chunks of code in comments. If the script prints "Could not copy file contents" that means that `copy()` returned `false`. The most likely reason is that file paths are wrong. Using relative paths is always risky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess (I know nothing about Joomla) is that [JUri](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUri.html) is a helper class to manipulate URLs. If that's your intention, you're using it wrong because your paths are missing the `http://` prefix. But I don't think you really want to copy files across the network (and the HTTP wrapper is read-only anyway). You have to use **file system** paths, not URLs. Joomla seems to have several path-related [constants](https://docs.joomla.org/Constants) so you can build an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [JFile native Joomla Class](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFile.html):

```
$sourspath = JUri::root().'media/truematrimony/profiles/pending/'.$totbookmar.'';

$descpath = JUri::root().'media/truematrimony/profiles/kmprofile/'.$totbookmar.''; 

$status = JFile::copy($sourspath, $descpath) or die("Could not copy file contents");
```

**Edit:**

Try to set folder permissions to write before copy function call:

```
chmod($descpath, 0644);
```

And if it still doesn't work, check your temp folder is correctly set up in your *Global Configuration* (and it also has the proper permissions to write in)

Comment: Then the issue may come from `$descpath` folder permissions.

Comment: Folder Permission 0755 for Both Folder

Comment: In that case, the issue is comming from your file content, @Karthikmathesh . Check it